# Workflow Error with multiple lines of text parameter

Tags: sharepoint-designer, multiline-text-field, workflow2013

Purpose of the workflow :
Duplicating an item and modifying some columns of the new item trough the workflow parameter initiation form. One of the editable columns is of type "multiple lines of text".

Issue:
When I put more than 255 characters in this field, the workflow stops as soon as it needs to use this parameter. It is also impossible to record it in the history.
However, with less than 255 characters it works.

Error Details:
After the workflow has been canceled, the following information appears in the status pages

```
Details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 500 {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],........} at   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at 
System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at     System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

My deduction:
Storing the information in the workflow process cuts out my string but can not rebuild it for use.

What do you think ? How can I get around it?

Comment: Are you specified the type of text to allow:  Plain or Rich Text ?

Comment: I have been trying with all types of text in my list (in case). In the workflow parameters initiation form i cannot select any type of text

Comment: is it a document library or list ?

Comment: It's a document library. And i've try with a list too. Same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a document library

- In column properties check `Allow unlimited length in document libraries:`

If it's a list

- `Append Changes to Existing Text`  set to **No**

**[Update]**

Unfortunately ,based on this [official article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292551.aspx#bkm_05) The maximum allowable length for strings in workflow text fields is 255 characters. If you set your text field to exceed this limit, its content will be truncated to 255 characters.

A workaround , you can create a list with multi-line column that holds the value that you need and add list item action to read this value from this list !

Comment: Already set all of this in the column parameters.  My problem is during the workflow part.

Comment: yes i know it's at workflow , and you try to add value for this column via workflow ? right ?

Comment: Yes, i can manually but not with workflow parameters initiation form.

Comment: now I understand you , unfortunately , The maximum allowable length for strings in workflow text fields is 255 characters. If you set your text field to exceed this limit, its content will be truncated to 255 characters. and this from Microsoft https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292551.aspx#bkm_05 let me update my answer with possible workaround

Comment: This is it. Thank you for your help. I will work like this.